# Spark plug fell into cylinder and I can't get out

Tags: ford, sparkplugs, escape

This is a on a 2016 1.6L Ford Escape. In picture 1 you can see the spark plug in trouble - it is too deep for some reason, we got the old one out but when we put in the new one, it fell too deep. The second picture shows what it is suppost to look like and it clearly looks different.

I already tried to use a magnet but we tightened it before we noticed what happened so it won't come up with a magnet.

[image: Spark plug sitting very low in socket]

[image: Spark plug sitting normally in socket]

Pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWnOp.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What pictures?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, sorry about that - it's added now

Comment: I watched a video of how to remove/replace the spark plugs. I thought you might have been missing something. I can unequivocally state, this has got to be one of the worst automotive engineering designs I've ever seen. I would think Ford would have put tubes down the hole to keep things clean/simple and allow for easy, unfettered access to the plugs. What a mess. I don't have an answer for you. My suggestion is to put the other plugs in, plant the coils, reinstall the wiring and see if you're just not seeing it correctly. I don't think its physically possible for one to be lower than another.

Comment: Check the plug you took out. Did a threaded insert sleeve come out with the plug? From the photos, the dark area around the lowered plug seems like the space where the sleeve is supposed to be.

Comment: How long is the spark plug boot for that plug? It might be longer than the others. (I also don't think it could be installed "deeper" than the others.)

Answer (score 1):

if you tighten it, the socket must have gone down with the plug, and if that is so, then the socket should go down to it again. if not then I would say it isn't tight/threaded into the head and maybe you can just pull it up with vise grips on the terminal un-threading  while lifting.  I agree that there could be a thread insert  that came out on old plug.

Answer (score 0):

The plug could hit the piston if you crank it and do damage.

You’ll need some kind of vacuum & hose that fits tight over the insulator to pull it out.. try some plumbing pipe reducers on a shop vac.with a rubber garden hose.  Improvise.